# How to minimize xorg gpu usage on ubuntu mate 18.04 laptop

Tags: ubuntu, xorg, nvidia, mate-desktop

I have a xiaomi air laptop with a very small gpu (MX150) and ubuntu mate 18.04 installed. I see that xorg uses up quite a bit of GPU (relative to what I have), around 185Mib on average.

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0       916      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           185MiB |
|    0      2495      G   fcitx-qimpanel                                 7Mi  |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Also any way to mitigate the fctix process ?

Am I right to think that this xorg uses gpu to render whatever theme I have installed? If so, how can I know which themes or mate features needs a lot? I am keen to minize this as I want to run ML models in there (No I don't have the money to buy gpu or use cloud).

Answer (score 0):

Are you running low on RAM? I use htop to keep on eye on my ram usage. Your GPU is probably using shared memory so it will pull from RAM as needed. fcitx-qimpanel seems to be part of Mate desktop.

MX150 is a dedicated Nvidia GeForce MX150 GPU. GPU is probably using the open source Nouveau drivers. You should get better performance with Nvidia proprietary drivers, but I suspect that means higher RAM usage.

https://www.linuxbabe.com/ubuntu/install-nvidia-driver-ubuntu-18-04

Xorg is required for managing displays. 185MB doesn't seem high, but lowering color depth from 32bit to 16bit, and lowering screen resolution are too ways to lower GPU ram usage. Some desktops use more ram than others. Try a lighter desktop like Lubuntu or Xubuntu is you need lower ram usage.

```
sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop
```

That should lower overall RAM usage.

If your laptop has at least 4GB of RAM I'd suspect you aren't having RAM usage issues with Ubuntu Mate 18.04. Standard installation of Mate is less than 1GB of total ram usage.

Comment: Yes I use htop, and the 4 cores and RAM are not at full capacity yet when one of my gpu heavy process shuts down because 'out of memory'!

Comment: Here are specs that might match your system : Graphics adapter
NVIDIA GeForce MX150 - 2048 MB, Core: 936 MHz, Memory: 1250 MHz, GDDR5, 390.77  If you are gaming at 1080p resolution then 2GB would be a the limiting factor. For Gaming install Nvidia driver and try 720p resolution. Also consider trying Mate 19.10 and next month 20.04. Both are a little faster overall in comparison to 18.04. Check Phoronix for some good benchmarks.